# HOPE Rebus Puzzle

Tags: riddle, rebus

Rebus puzzle is depicted as shown. (Ignore the red underline)

---

[image]

Comment: Is the red underline intentional or is MS Word suggesting that you should delete the repeated word?

Comment: I hope hope for the end of Comic Sans MS...

Comment: I wonder, why the post was voted down. Seems to be a fair puzzle. Assuming OP is new to this platform, quality of the image could be neglected

Comment: Raise Snipping Tool awareness!

Comment: @me_digvijay I'm not complaining, it even adds something to the riddle, you don't know if it's part of it, or just a red herring

Comment: @remus , is one of the below answers correct?  If not, would you consider adding a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe we have:

> High hopes

[30 chars]

Answer (score 0):

> Hope after hope. The underlined hope is the one that's after the other one.

Answer (score 0):

> "Hope against hope" where against = next to. I'm guessing the underline is just because a text editor assumed a word was typed twice by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

> From hope to nope with mistakes (spelling)

Answer (score -1):

It says:

> I underline no hope left

Comment: Try explaining why. Welcome to Puzzling SE though!

Comment: Thanks. Not obvious? I guessed that because the "HOPE" on the left is not underlined.

Comment: This solution doesn't really make any sense. Rebus solutions are supposed to be common sayings. (See other answers for examples)